# Where to load my array?

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {


goals = [[NSArray alloc] init];
goals = [[self.operation valueForKeyPath:@"goal.goalNaam"] allObjects]  ;


[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I'm loading my elements for my tableview in viewwillappear, as you can see in the code above. When the user adds something to the table (adding happens in a different view), it's added to Core Data and the array is loaded when the tableview is again appearing (after the dismissed "add-an-element-view"), now I want to delete something from the table. But the problem is that we're now staying in the same view (the tableview), so my array is not reloading (cause the viewwillappear is not executed). Anybody an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: After they do the code for the delete, make it call [self.tableView reloadData], that should do it.

Comment: No, I tried, I think there's a difference between viewwillappear and reloaddata. Reloaddata is used for numbersofrowsinsection and cellforrowatindex, while viewwillappear is executed literally when the viewwillappear

Comment: @Fuzej: what happened when you called reloaddata after the delete code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call "[self viewWillAppear:YES];" after delete the data from Core data, So the datas are reloaded from the same view (Tableview)

Answer (score 0):

You load your data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  This is called as cells come into view, and only cells in view (or almost in view) are loaded.

To force something to be reloaded, use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` or one of the other `reload...` methods.

Comment: Yes indeed, but things will be reloaded from the same array, so nothing will change, i think. The arrays are only reloaded when the viewwillappear is called.

Comment: The arrays are loaded when you load the arrays.

Comment: True, this opened my eyes. Doesn't matter where I load them, or if I'd load them twice.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) . You can set your VC as the fetch result delegate, and be notified when the data structure changes.